# WSO2 IoT Can not run IoT Analytics server

Tags: java, wso2, iot, wso2-iot

Windows 10
JDK version 8.0.45

I downloaded and installed the WSO2 IoT 3.0.0.

I followed steps here to run servers:
docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Running+the+Product#995f288dd90d4800a671282c23a2cb68

(installed plugins ok)
run [broker ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9jhL.png)
run [core ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mRcY.png)
run **analytics error**:

`JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Softver\WSO2\WSO2IO~1.0\ANALYT~1\bin\..
Loading spark environment variables
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,171] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 8.1 6.3, amd64
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_45
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.45-b02,Oracle Corporation
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\Softver\WSO2\WSO2IO~1.0\ANALYT~1\bin\..
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\Softver\WSO2\WSO2IO~1.0\ANALYT~1\bin\..\tmp
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,187] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : karjam, en-US, Europe/Prague
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,343] [IoT-Analytics]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The running OS : Windows 8.1 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon
[2017-08-02 14:28:33,343] [IoT-Analytics]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.`

End of log:

`[2017-08-02 14:29:31,437] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.eventsink.AnalyticsEventStoreDeployer} -  Deployed successfully analytics event store: org_wso2_iot_devices_wordcount.xml
[2017-08-02 14:29:34,234] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-08-02 14:29:36,906] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-08-02 14:29:37,890] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
MqttException (128)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.subscribe(MqttClient.java:295)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-08-02 14:29:39,805] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.manager.core.internal.CarbonEventManagementService} -  Starting polling event receivers
[2017-08-02 14:29:50,399] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-08-02 14:29:53,118] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Client is connected (32100)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.connect(MqttAsyncClient.java:465)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient.connect(MqttClient.java:238)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.startListener(MQTTAdapterListener.java:200)
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener.run(MQTTAdapterListener.java:269)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Any ideas? First time problem like this with WSO2 product (already used esb, dss, ..).

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 IoT 3.1.0](http://wso2.com/iot/) is released and it has fixed many issues. Can you please try running the new WSO2 IoT 3.1.0?